# How can I select two values from another table using collection _select in form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to link a `first_name` and `last_name` from an Employees table in a form, so a user can select an Employee by their whole name.

The `first_name` and `last_name` work on their own, but I would like to have both values.

I tried different types of brackets to no avail.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :employee, as: 'Sales Rep' %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:employee, @employees,:id,(:first_name, :last_name) ) %>
    </div>
```

Comment: the objects in the `@employees` collection come from the `Employee` `ActiveRecord` model ?. If so, you could write a method in that model like `def full_name; "#{first_name}" #{last_name};end`, and then use that in your form like: `<%= f.collection_select(:employee, @employees, :id, :full_name) ) %>`

Comment: @fanta, perfect! If you would like to add your comment as an answer, I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by adding a new method to your `Employee` model like:

```rb
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

and use that method in your form:

```rb
<%= f.collection_select(:employee, @employees, :id, :full_name) %>
```